# ES6 Assign a class method to HTML Element Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to place HTML Content within a div dynamically. This content when clicked should do a function.
I have the function in a class. How can I assign this function to onclick method.
A stripped down sample(non working) [here](https://codepen.io/sc0rp1on/pen/YzwJNdx).
I know I can assign an onclick event listener but I want to know how this can be implemented

```
class A{
  log(){
    console.log('test')
  }
}

class B extends A{
  write(){
    let z = '<span class="botSmartButtonSpan" onclick="super.log()"></span>';
    document.getElementById('x').innerHTML=z;
  }
}

let obj = new B();
obj.write();
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('x').firstChild.onclick=super.log`  (Although you really shouldn't do it that way, and your example is doing something presumably you would not do in real code.  It'd get messy very quickly even if you made it work.)  Also, `super` is a syntax feature  only allowed in specific contexts (because it is only relevant in those contexts)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Answer (score 3):

`onclick` attribute values are evaluated in a different scope. `super` isn't defined there. You can't achieve this by mashing strings together.

Use DOM methods instead.

```
write(){
  let z = document.createElement("span");
  z.classList.add("botSmartButtonSpan");
  z.addEventListener("click", () => this.log());
  document.getElementById('x').appendChild(z);
}
```

Comment: is there a reason you changed it to `this.log()`?  (there's nothing wrong with it obviously, and super doesn't actually have meaning the way it's currently written, especially given this is a really contrived example that should be refactored before it has even begun) but its intent is still different?

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Yes, this will work, but what I showed was a small statement. I have dynamically change a lot of content in a same way. Consider it like a list of buttons doing running different functions. This process makes it really long to code that way while the string method does it in a few lines.